# A large amount of writes on ESP32 spiffs/fatfs

Tags: esp32, fatfs, spiffs

I have a battery powered `EPS32` project that runs a task every 10 minutes for about 10 seconds and is in deep sleep the rest of the time. I am having some problems and need to to do diagnostics by writing data to the `EPS32` flash **after each task**.

I see that the `Arduino IDE` supports the use of `spiffs` and `fatfs` and as far as I know, both support wear levelling. However, I need to write a few numbers every 10 minutes and that means a lot of writes, which can eventually wear out the flash.

Since I am only going to be **adding** information, is there a good strategy to avoid rewriting all the data every time I add new data? Which method should I use, `spiffs` or `fatfs`? When I open the file in **append** mode and add data, will the entire file be rewritten each time?

PS. I could probably add an external SD card, but I want to keep power consumption as low as possible.

PSS. The data could also be stored as an array of integers, but can I create such an array in `spiffs` or `fatfs`?

Comment: Use [RTC Memory](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/memory-types.html#rtc-slow-memory), it survives deep sleep but not power-cycle, and no wearing effect.

Comment: @hcheung The problem is that these data are collected on a battery-powered device. How can I access them if I don't disconnect the device from the battery and then connect it to the computer? In the meantime, the data are lost.

Comment: You said "deep sleep" in your post, deep sleep is not disconnect from power. RTC data will not go away during deep sleep, nor from restart(), only from lost of power.

Comment: @hcheung I said and I meant deep sleep.  You proposed that I collect the data using RTC memory during deep sleeps, and that is fine.  But I don't know how to get collected data to the computer without turning ESP32 off and lost the data at the end of the process.

Comment: No, you collect data BEFORE deep sleep, and assign to the RTC memory variable, as long as the variable is RTC memory, going into deep sleep will not lost the data. Take a look at the [SmoothBlink_ULP_Code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/DeepSleep/SmoothBlink_ULP_Code/SmoothBlink_ULP_Code.ino) example, if it not suitable for your use case, then you need to elaborate what you want and how is your current code look like.